# Is there a way to change default values of a core data attribute

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I would like to change the default value of some of the attributes in my core data model dynamically.

For instance, my app deals with real estate investment, and I have an attribute pertaining to interest rate (the type Float). If the user enters an interest rate of 3.5% (float value would be 3.5) for a particular property they are analyzing, I would like the value for the next property they analyze to automatically populate with 3.5.

Is there a way to accomplish this without subclassing NSManagedObject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question - by default, managed objects are initialized with the default values given in the managed object model. But like you say, sometimes you might want a dynamic default value (the example Apple use in their own documentation is using the current date/time as a default value).

Unfortunately I don't believe there's a way to do this without subclassing `NSManagedObject`. There's an Apple recommended way to do this - rather than overriding the `init` method (not recommended), you instead use the `awakeFromInsert` method, which is called when the object in question is first inserted into the managed object context.

Here's what Apple say from their own docs:

> `awakeFromInsert:`
>
> You typically use this method to initialize special default property values. This method is invoked only once in the object's lifetime.
>
> If you want to set attribute values in an implementation of this method, you should typically use primitive accessor methods (either `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:` or—better—the appropriate custom primitive accessors). This ensures that the new values are treated as baseline values rather than being recorded as undoable changes for the properties in question.

So to answer your original question - I can't think of a way to do this without subclassing `NSManagedObject`, and subclassing is the officially recommended approach for handling dynamic default values.

Comment: Yep. There's no need to be scared of subclassing NSManagedObject, there are tools such as mogenerator that make it a breeze

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand how to use awakeFromInsert to set a default value. the next question becomes, where do I store all of the default values? Perhaps I should keep one "default" copy of my object model and reference that in the awakeFromInsert method. When the user changes the interest rate, it will update the current objects value as well as the "default object" value.